# how to allow Windows Azure Services in SQL Azure via REST API

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a problem with Windows Azure Rest API create server.

I am able to create an SQL Azure Server via REST API but my problem is that i need it to have the ALLOWED SERVICES = "WINDOWS AZURE SERVICES" set to YES by default. This is very important to me because my website auto generates the servers and databases. If this option is set to NO, the import rest api sends back a 400 bad request response. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For enabling Windows Azure Services to access the server, you will need to configure a firewall rule. To create a firewall rule with REST that allows Azure Services to access the server, use [create firewall rule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn505712.aspx). For Windows Azure Services make the start and end ID address 0.0.0.0.

The Request body should look something like the following.

```
<ServiceResource xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure">
     <Name>AllowAzureServices</Name>
     <StartIPAddress>0.0.0.0</StartIPAddress>
     <EndIPAddress>0.0.0.0</EndIPAddress>
</ServiceResource>
```

Comment: For anyone attempting to do DacPac or .bacpac file imports into Azure via the Azure REST managment API for SQL Server, you must add this rule to allow internal Azure IP addresses to access your SQL Server instance. 

If you cannot add this rule for business reasons or technical reasons, there is a work around. You must create a VM within Azure, and use the DacPacx API to tell your VM to handle the import for you. 

Also, if you add a rule for ranges 0.0.0.0 to 0.0.0.0, it will not be displayed within the Firewall rules table. It will only switch on the Allow Azure Services switch.